# Style multiple buttons at once [Javafx]

Tags: java, javafx

I've searched and seen a couple other questions similar to this one, but they don't really answer my question. I have a set of buttons that all look the same, and currently I'm changing the style on each button individually, like so:

```
button1.setBackground(background);
button1.setPrefHeight(height);
button1.setPrefWidth(width);

button2.setBackground(background);
button2.setPrefHeight(height);
button2.setPrefWidth(width);
```

And so on. I tried the following to no avail:

```
templateButton.setBackground(background);
templateButton.setPrefHeight(height);
templateButton.setPrefWidth(width);
button1 = templateButton;
button2 = templateButton;
button3 = templateButton;
```

But then I get an error stating "duplicate children added", which I'm assuming means buttons 1/2/3 all point to templateButton somehow, instead of just inheriting templateButton's properties. Is there a better way to do this or should I just set them all up separately?

Comment: `button1/2/3 = templateButton` points all those references to the same object (`templateButton`).

Comment: @Oli yeah, that's what I thought but I haven't coded in a while so I'm a bit rusty and forgot some technicalities/things' proper names ;)

Comment: Community, how did you manage to figure out that this question is a duplicate of the one I flagged if you are not a real person :O. Freaky stuff I must say..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to apply style to controls in JavaFX is using CSS, preferably in an external style sheet. As well as offering a nice separation between layout code and style code, this also allows you to style multiple scene graph nodes at once.

To apply to all buttons in the application, you can use

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: ... ;
    -fx-pref-height: ... ;
    -fx-pref-width: ... ;
}
```

To apply to a select group of buttons, you can give those buttons a style class:

```
Button button1 = new Button(...);
Button button2 = new Button(...);
Button button3 = new Button(...);

Stream.of(button1, button2, button3).forEach(button -> 
    button.getStyleClass().add("my-style"));
```

And then the selector in the css file becomes

```
.my-style {
    -fx-background-color: ... ;
    /* etc */
}
```

Or, if all the buttons are in a particular layout pane, you can select all buttons in the layout pane:

```
Button button1 = new Button(...);
Button button2 = new Button(...);
Button button3 = new Button(...);

VBox buttons = new VBox(button1, button2, button3);
buttons.getStyleClass().add("button-container");
```

and then the CSS selector is

```
.button-container > .button {
    /* styles.... */
}
```